# MySQL indexes and performance

Tags: mysql

i have got a conceptual doubt about how MySQL indexes impacts over the performance.

Is the unique index only for constraints ? Does not impact over the queries performance ?

Can i define an index over a foreign key to improve the queries performance ?

Comment: There's an entire [chapter of the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/optimization.html) dedicated to explaining this. As an exercise consider how useless an un-ordered phone book would be compared to one with names in alphabetical order.

Comment: Along with @tadman's great advice, you will also want to take a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain-output.html for use with a specific query.